# Update Github checklist on commit / pull request

Tags: git, github, git-commit, pull-request

Just like you can [close and issue via commit / pull request](https://github.com/blog/1506-closing-issues-via-pull-requests) on Github, is it possible to update a [checklist (a.k.a task-list)](https://help.github.com/articles/about-task-lists/) in a similar way???

What I mean is if there exist some [special syntax](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/) to do this, instead of manually going to Github and clicking on the check boxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have received an e-mail from Github staff:

> Hey David,
>
> I'm afraid this isn't currently possible but it's a neat idea, I'll
>   add it to our Feature Request List.
>
> I can't promise if or when we would add this but I will for sure pass
>   it along.

So it's not possible right now.